# DD-WRT Cant connect to web interface

Tags: dd-wrt

I just flashed this to my netgear R8000 router and it shows up in the networks but my mac says it cannot find server when ever i type in the 192.168.1.1 to pull up the web interface.

Comment: are you sure that is the correct IP? I vaguely recall 192.168.0.1 was the IP that DD-WRT used

Comment: It is not 192.168.0.1

Comment: What's your default gateway?

Comment: it would be 192.168.1.1 But it cant connect to it on this 
i also tried 10.0.0.1

Comment: Connect a single computer to your router. Connect your router to "internet" (WAN) if possible. Start the router, let it initialize, then start your computer and launch a web browser. Regardless of OS (which you didn't tell) there may well pop up a webpage created by the router. If it doesn't, first check `ipconfig /all` or `ifconfig` in cmd.com / shell to see if you have an IP set for the wire-interface to the router; if not you need to remedy that (which is beyond this comment).

Comment: Are you able to telnet or ssh into your router?

Comment: What does the routing table on your computer say?   Are you able to connect to the Internet through your router?

Comment: I am not able to connect to the internet on it currently And also due to how my macbook is set up im not able to telnet or ssh into my router on this.